# How to run a script on a slave node from Master's System Groovy script in a Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I know that in groovy pipeline scripts you can run certain scriptblock in slave workspace, but can you do similar thing from a job system groovy command?

Comment: can you share more about what you are trying to accomplish? maybe include a minimal Jenkinsfile that mostly works?

Comment: @burnettk I have same request to run system groovy script on salve machines. What more you need?